# Get output of existing process

Tags: c#, .net, process, output

Can I get output of **existing proccess**? When I'm trying it says process is not running or doesn't have output redirect. Example I launched ping google.com -t (waited 20 seconds to have ouput) and I want last 10 lines from it:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("PING").FirstOrDefault(); 
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Any ideas how I can get it?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible without launching the program you are wanting to monitor in some kind of "special way", if it was started by just typing it's name in a console window I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: No file name was specified in the Process.StartInfo
P.S. I tried it some minutes back.